# Nuclide debugger does not launch for React Native

Tags: debugging, react-native

### Steps to Reproduce / Screenshots

Apply all operations from [the instruction](https://nuclide.io/docs/platforms/react-native/) :

1. Start the React Native Server. Done. It successfully listenings port 8081.
   [image: Start the React Native Server. Done.]
2. Run the application with "$ react-native run-ios". Done.
   [image: Run the application]
3. Prime the Debugger (From the Command Palette, launch "Nuclide React Native: Start Debugging"). Done.
   [image: Prime the Debugger]
   [image: Prime the Debugger]
4. Enable Debugging from the Application - select "Debug JS Remotely". Done.
   [image: Enable Debugging from the Application]
5. "...After you enable debugging from the simulated application, Nuclide will attach to that debugging process automatically, since we primed the Debugger above..." **BUT it does not start/work**!

### Environment

Atom version 1.15.0

Nuclide plugin version 0.209.0

React Native version: 0.42

Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): iOS

Device info
Simulator/Device? - Simulator iOS 10.2 / iOS 8.1

OS version? - MacOS 10.12.3

Debug/Release? - Debug

$ apm ls --installed
Community Packages (17)

├── atom-beautify@0.29.17

├── atom-react-native-autocomplete@0.0.27

├── atom-react-native-css@1.1.3

├── busy-signal@1.3.0

├── file-icons@2.0.17

├── flow@0.5.3

├── intentions@1.1.2

├── language-babel@2.56.2

├── language-javascript-jsx@0.3.7

├── linter@2.1.0

├── linter-ui-default@1.2.1

├── minimap@4.26.8

├── nuclide@0.210.0

├── react-es6-snippets@0.3.0

├── react-native-snippets@0.3.0

├── react-snippets@0.7.2

└── redux-snippets@0.2.2

---

So, my application works fine, packager/React Native Server works fine, I successfully see my logs in Chrome dev tolls, **BUT Nuclide debugger does not work/start**, it still in "Starting debugger mode"

[image: it still in "Starting debugger mode"]

May be someone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I also created new simple RN example and install RN ver "0.42.0-rc.3" but it did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the debugger before you start the iOS simulator so that the simulator doesn't open a Chrome debugger which will hog the port.

To expand on that a little, I was getting the exact same experience and what was happening was that when I started the iOS Simulator it was opening a Chrome window for debugging. This happens if the Nuclide debugger isn't already running when debugging is enabled in the simulator.

Comment: with your hint the situation is changed, debugger went into status "The debugee is currently running." ([screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/db7c5b988787270e9ff3a9bd7b93de5f.png)) BUT I see in simulator blank white screen only ([screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/de42e11ba073072d604655381569dffb.png)). For testing purposes I've also created new blank proj, but nothing changed, I see the same white screen only. When I disable "Remote JS Remotely" I see expected screen with working app ([screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/bfefe05f0a8328d9329ce925e6428392.png)). Can you advice? Thanks.

Comment: @Stich are you running the latest Nuclide? What happens if you enable debugging after starting the app in the simulator (I mean once the working app is running)?

Comment: @Stich given that I got you past the problem described and what you have now is a new problem you could mark my answer as the correct. :-D

Comment: "are you running the latest Nuclide?" - yes, at this moment it is 0.214.0

"What happens if you enable debugging after starting the app in the simulator" - I see the same white screen again.

Comment: thanks, I have created [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154551/react-native-app-stuck-on-blank-white-screen-with-remote-debugging-using-nuclide) regarding the issue with blank white screen using Nuclide debugger.